# C pointers array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

From external code I receive a struct:

```
struct some_list {
    void *data;
    int length;
};
```

where data is a pointer to the first element of array of `*char`.

Now when I receive struct I of course can get the length of array, and theoretically knowing the size of pointers I should be able to iterate through all of them and print the strings using `printf`.

When I try to print it with following code I get segfault:

```
struct some_list result = get_list();
printf("Array length: %d\n", result.length);
int j;
for(j=0;j<result.length;j++){
    printf("%d's element in array is: %s\n", j+1, (((char *)result.data)[j]));
}
```

How would I get my values?

Comment: Is it "spam tags" day again? C and C++ are **different** languages.

Comment: Okay, sorry, C++ popped up in recommended tags.

Comment: why `data` is `void*` and not `char*` ?

Comment: There are no "recommended tags"! Just character matches. Do you add all words in SMS which show up? And provide a [mcve]. Using `void *` without need is most times a bad idea.

Comment: @LPs Yes, it is an array of pointers. So the entire struct is represents an array of strings.

Comment: @Olaf Not me picked to use void there, I am getting it from another code to which I only have .h and nothing else.

Comment: Hmm, such code always makes me suspicious. Mabe I'm a pessimist, but then it is long time experience.

Comment: @Olaf well, I've never seen such code before this is why I am stuck here and. I don't even see how it gets packed into this. All I have is .h definition and my knowledge that it should return array of strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `data` is indeed a pointer to the first element of array of `char*`, then you need to do this:

```
char **p = result.data;
int j;
for(j=0; j<result.length; j++){
    printf("%d's element in array is: %s\n", j+1, p[j]);
}
```

While in your code `(((char *)result.data)[j]))` does not even evaluate to a string, it is a char.

Comment: Just replacing `(((char *)result.data)[j]))` by `(((char **)result.data)[j]))` would do as well. They way you do it is much cleaner, nicer though ... :)